# UPDATE query not using WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-update, where-clause

I am trying to use an UPDATE query to modify a field in a table from a field in another table.

The query statement I'm using is:

```
UPDATE Todays_Deliveries SET Remaining = DLookup("Remaining","Current_Delivery","[MP-Ref] = Form![MP-Ref] And [Cat No] ='" & [Cat No] & "'")
WHERE "[MP-Ref] = Form![MP-Ref] And [Cat No] ='" & [Cat No] & "'";
```

MP-Ref is the delivery reference.

Cat No is the item reference.

Where Todays_Deliveries is a table with the total records related to items coming in from deliveries on a given day. The user selects a delivery using a form which then uses an APPEND query to populate the Current_Delivery table based on the delivery reference. Once the user is finished the Current_Delivery table is cleared using a DELETE query.

Both tables have a *Remaining* value with the total number of a particular record that still needs to be booked in. The query updates the Todays_Deliveries table when the user modifies the *Remaining* field of the Current_Delivery on the Current_Delivery form. Everything works fine but any records that aren't in the Current_Delivery table when the query is run are updated to NULL.

Removing the WHERE clause seems to have no impact on the results, which leads me to believe I am not utalising the WHERE clause correctly.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your whole Where clause is enclosed within double-quotes.
That is a bit odd even for Ms Access.

Try this :

```
UPDATE Todays_Deliveries 
SET Remaining = DLookup("Remaining","Current_Delivery","[MP-Ref] = Form![MP-Ref] And [Cat No] ='" & [Cat No] & "'")
WHERE [MP-Ref] = Form![MP-Ref] And [Cat No] =  "'" & [Cat No] & "'";
```

Comment: I bet that's the problem! I've spent all day on this. I've been kicked out of the building, I'll have to try it out tomorrow. Thanks for your input

Comment: It's still not working. The Form! before [Mp-Ref] is causing an error of too few parameters any idea why it works in the dlookup but not the WHERE clause?